# grub can't find grub.cfg when booting from zfs root

Tags: boot, grub2, zfs

I installed Xubuntu 14.04 on a ZFS-root following these instructions using ZoL's Debian repo:
https://github.com/fajarnugraha/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem

The system works well, but when booting, grub goes directly into grub shell. There I can run `configfile (hd0,msdos3)/ROOT/ubuntu/@/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the usual grub menu starts and I can boot my system.
It seems to me grub can't find `grub.cfg` by itself.

The instructions actually say the path is `(hd0,msdos3)/ROOT/ubuntu@/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (notice the `@`). But this didn't work for me. I had to put a / before the @. But I guess this is not relevant. (3.5 test boot from existing grub installation)

Grub was installed with `grub-install --boot-directory=/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/boot /dev/sda` as per the instructions.

Anyway, after a few reboots I noticed there is actually a real folder `/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/boot` and also a folder `/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/@/boot` which contain a grub folder with about everything but a `grub.cfg`:

```
$ ls -l /rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/boot/grub/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     3 Jan 30 21:34 fonts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   699 Jan 31 11:04 gfxblacklist.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1024 Jan 30 21:34 grubenv
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   273 Jan 30 21:47 i386-pc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     5 Jan 30 21:47 locale
```

`/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/@/boot/grub/` contains the same.

I copied `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to both locations and now it's working.
My actual problem  is that if something updates grub, I have to copy `grub.cfg` again. For now I added 2 lines to `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` to do the copying on every `grub-update`. But when the grub package is updated this change will be gone. So I'm looking for a reliable solution here.

**One further thought:**

Could it be that `/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/` should also hold my filesystem? Because other than the `boot` directory it's empty:

```
# ls -l /rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/
total 17
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 3 Jän 30 21:40 @
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 3 Jän 30 21:34 boot
```

**Here some infos that may be useful:**

```
# zfs list
NAME                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool              4,15G  94,3G   144K  /rpool
rpool/ROOT         4,15G  94,3G  7,09M  /rpool/ROOT
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  4,14G  94,3G  4,01G  /rpool/ROOT/ubuntu
```

zfs-related part of `mount`:

```
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu on / type zfs (rw,relatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool on /rpool type zfs (rw,relatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/ROOT on /rpool/ROOT type zfs (rw,relatime,xattr,noacl)
```

Any help is appreciated. If you need more infos let me know.

FWIW: My only prior knowledge of ZFS is from using freenas, this is my first attempt to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Some corrections from my own experience.

1. Your "rpool" was mounted at "/rpool" automatically at the time you created rpool. That's why somewhere in the configuration process you issue `zfs set mountpoint=none rpool` in order to eliminate that behavior. The same you do for `rpool/ROOT` to eliminate its automatic mounting at /rpool/ROOT, which you don't need.
2. In fact, your zpool is "rpool", while "rpool/ROOT" is a ZFS dataset and not a zpool.
3. With `grub-install` you can only refer to the current directory tree. That's why you give it `--boot-directory=/boot`. The script itself doesn't want to hear anything about ZFS. But further in the process other auxiliary scripts included with GRUB2 will check what's mounted there and make sure grub can access it at boot time. So if you use the most recent version of ZFS, as of the date of this writing, GRUB2 will NOT recognize it and will refuse to install there. Alas!
4. You sure put "/" before "@" and it IS relevant, as you yourself admit it DIDN'T work for you otherwise. EDIT: well, it USED to matter, but with the last git code it doesn't.
5. Lastly, booting into snapshots is not supported, I'm afraid. That is to say, while you CAN tell GRUB to use something like `(hd0,2)mypool/ROOT/myfs@version` etc., your actual boot will be not what you expect. So don't do that.

Comment: I know I'm a year late, but thanks for the clarifications! I'm still no ZFS master, but my system is still running with no problems, just doing the occasional zpool scrub.

Answer (score 0):

I just figued it out:

The `grub-install` command was wrong. `--boot-directory` needs to be `/boot` instead of `/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/boot`.

Now I did `grub-install --boot-directory=/boot`, deleted the boot folders in `/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu` and `/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu/@` and it boots just fine.

Let me try to explain:

`/rpool` and `/rpool/ROOT` are my zpools. They are mounted there so I can access the datasets I may create in those pools, I think. The folder `/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu` is unnecessary, it was just copied there while copying the filesystem from the termporary ext4-fs to the ZFS pool. I deleted it now.

Grub finds the config file in `/boot` just fine, because it knows ZFS. It even finds my snapshots. Thats what the paths with `@` are for:

In grub shell I can use `(hd0,msdos3)/ROOT/ubuntu` or `(hd0,msdos3)/ROOT/ubuntu@` for the actual current filesystem, or if I have a snapshot called "version-1" I can tell grub to use `(hd0,msdos3)/ROOT/ubuntu@version-1`. Should be the same on the kernel command line to boot with a snapshot as root filesystem like `linux /ROOT/ubuntu/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu@version-1` but I haven't tried that yet. Probably have to load the previous kernel if it was updated after taking the snapshot.